# SSL Certificate: Displays correctly for some and not others

Tags: ssl, certificate, domain

[image]Is it possible anyone can check out this site:

https://www.goweryarns.co.uk/

For me and 80% of my customers, it works, fine. Yet for some 20% they see this error:

NET:: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

If anyone can get this error, I would love to do some testing and see what you view for the certification path.

Comment: [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.goweryarns.co.uk) shows at least the wrong order of certificates in the chain. Maybe this is the problem, maybe not - there are too few information about what the other customers really experience and how there setup is. There might for example also some DNS problems involved (maybe they use a DNS server which returns the wrong address).

Comment: This is why I needed testing, as all I get back is that error from customers. I need to be on that pc in order to test more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yet for some 20% they see this error: NET:: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

One explanation might be that they are accessing the site via *https://goweryarns.com* or *https://www.goweryarns.com*, neither of which appears to have an associated SSL certificate. A generic wildcard certificate seems to be returned instead:

[image: Invalid SSL Certificate Screenshot]

- The error shown above is returned by Firefox while `NET:: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` is returned by Chrome.
- The *oxatis.com* domain is associated with *[gandi.net](https://www.gandi.net/en)* (the apparent registrar for the [*.com* version of the *goweryarns* domain name](https://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=goweryarns.com&type=domain) and through whom your [certificate for the *.co.uk* version of the domain name](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.goweryarns.co.uk) appears to be issued).

**Why is this occuring?**

Assuming this is the problem, it's because certificate checking (if any) happens before website redirection (which entails a new request). In short:

- The browser requests e.g. *https://www.goweryarns.com*.
- The server, having no certificate for that domain, gives back a default certificate for *oxatis.com*.
- The browser interrupts the transaction and displays an error regarding the domain name mismatch before the server can return the information necessary to redirect the browser to *https://www.goweryarns.co.uk/*.

Redirection for *http://goweryarns.com* and *http://www.goweryarns.com* likely works because there is no initial certificate request for *goweryarns.com* or *www.goweryarns.com* with simple HTTP.

**How can this be resolved?**

Barring any other issues, the simple fix would likely be to either:

- Get a new, single certificate that covers *goweryarns.com*, *www.goweryarns.com*, *goweryarns.co.uk* and *www.goweryarns.co.uk* (rather than just *goweryarns.co.uk* and *www.goweryarns.co.uk* [as is currently the case](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.goweryarns.co.uk)).
- Get additional certificates that cover *goweryarns.com* and *www.goweryarns.com* (in addition to the one you have now for the *.co.uk* versions).

Note that this assumes that it's possible to serve a valid certificate when either *https://goweryarns.com* or *https://www.goweryarns.com* is requested. If your redirects come directly from the registrar, you may (or may not) need to change how you redirect your domains.

**Let's Encrypt Certificates**

- If you want free valid certificates for *goweryarns.com* and *www.goweryarns.com*, you should have a look at [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) (and more specifically ZeroSSL). [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com) provides a web interface and a cross-platform command line utility for issuing and managing Let's Encrypt certificates. Let's Encrypt supports multiple domains on a single certificate, so you can have both *goweryarns.com* and *www.goweryarns.com* on the same certificate as well.
- The only downside to Let's Encrypt certificates is that they currently must be renewed once every 3 months (they can be used indefinitely this way, however). Even if this isn't something you wish to deal with in the long run to save some money, they could still be relevant for simple testing (to work out connection kinks) without additional monetary outlay.

---

**Additional Requested Screenshots**

*https://goweryarns.com (Chrome)*

[image: Invalid SSL Certificate Screenshot 2]

*https://www.goweryarns.com - (Chrome)*

[image: Invalid SSL Certificate Screenshot 3]

*Certification Path - https://goweryarns.com and https://www.goweryarns.com (Chrome)*

[image: Bad Certification Path]

*Certification Path - https://goweryarns.co.uk and https://www.goweryarns.co.uk (Chrome)*

[image: Good Certification Path]

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the error, which shows they are accessing the correct site, but getting the error you have shown. When you visit the site does it work ok for you?

Comment: I have added the (originally) requested screenshots. All versions of the *goweryarns.co.uk* domain (`http/https`, with and without the leading `www`) work for me (they all redirect or load without error) and have worked 100% of the time (I cannot reproduce the exact screenshot you have posted). The same applies to the `http` versions of *goweryarns.com* and *www.goweryarns.com* (100% success rate).

Comment: However, I *can* reliably reproduce the same error for *https:// goweryarns.com* and *https://www.goweryarns.com* and SSL Labs apparently has the same issue of the incorrect certificate being returned identified in my answer -- [gowersyarns.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=goweryarns.com) and [www.goweryarns.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.goweryarns.com)

Answer (score 2):

**NET:: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID** error indicates the browser is not able to identify the secured connection.

Two simple solutions you need to keep in your mind to get rid of it.

1. Rearrange the Chain Certificates, if chain certificates are not in a uniform manner, the browser shows the error.
2. Reinstall the SSL with updated TLS version. If your website is secured under the older TLS version, the modern browser does not accept it and block the secured connection.

Comment: But this doesn't explain why it works for a large test audience. While only some seem to get the error. When you visit the site does it work ok for you?